# audio link produces black box

Tags: audio, html5

In chrome and firefox (and maybe others) the audio link does not render a media controller.  E.g.

```
[audio http://example.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/file.mp3]
```

In Chrome, view page source show this code in place:

```
<div id="mep_0" class="mejs-container" style="width: 400px; height: 30px; ">    
  <div class="mejs-inner"><div class="mejs-mediaelement">
    <audio id="wp_mep_1" preload="none">
    <object width="400" height="30" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://example.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="movie" value="http://example.com/wp/wp-content/plugins/media-element-html5-video-and-audio-player/mediaelement/flashmediaelement.swf">
        <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=">            
    </object>       
</audio></div><div class="mejs-layers"></div><div class="mejs-controls"></div><div class="mejs-clear"></div></div></div>
```

UPDATE:
In the JS console I note an error:

```
mediaelement-and-player.min.js:36
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined
```

Comment: Is the path to the file correct? I see under `flashvars`, `file=` is empty, so it would make sense that nothing is loading.

Comment: @Milo, yes I believe so (I tested it OK).  I have just updated question with a JS error...

Comment: it's difficult to say without seeing it in context. is jQuery being sourced properly in your theme? maybe try the default theme and disabling other plugins to see if there's a conflict.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @Milo.  I am seeing different behaviour depending on which plugin is activated.  I'm going to step through them methodically to work it out....

Comment: OK, it's the `MediaElement.js - HTML5 Audio and Video` plugin which produces the black box.  Without it I get nothing.  See here: (http://butterflyhurricane.com/)

Comment: I was assuming there was a conflict with another plugin, but the issue is just the format of your shortcode. sorry, I missed that. I added an answer with the correct format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shortcode:

```
[audio http://example.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/file.mp3]
```

should be:

```
[audio src="http://example.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/file.mp3"]
```

Note the `src=""` around the filename.